# AppleScript Progress Bar with Reboot Button

Tags: applescript, reboot

I've recently been tasked with working on a project to switch antivirus software in the environment as we are changing to a new vendor.  Naturally, this kind of effort will require a reboot on our endpoints once the old A/V software has been removed.

What I'm trying to do is create a reboot notification prompt for our Mac customers (since many are high up on the food chain) to let them know what we are doing.

This prompt will let them know they have 3 hours to reboot their Macs to complete the removal of the software if they are logged in.  If they do not reboot within 3 hours, their workstation will automatically reboot.

Applescript has a great workflow that allows me to effectively communicate with our users, but I would like to change the Stop button to a reboot, so that our customers can reboot their Macs on demand.

I will work in logic later on to automatically reboot if they are not logged in.

I modified one of the scripts that I, "borrowed," from here
https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=46572

```
-- Progress Bar - Reboot Timer

progress_timer("03:00:00", "Reboot Timer") -- call the progress timer with an HMS time and timer label
return result

------------------------------------------
-- subroutines in alphabetical order --
------------------------------------------

-- getTimeConversion converts a time in HMS format (hh:mm:ss) to a time in seconds
on getTimeConversion(HMS_Time)
    set HMSlist to the words of HMS_Time -- get {hh, mm, ss} from HMS time (p. 158 Rosenthal)
    set theHours to item 1 of HMSlist
    set theMinutes to item 2 of HMSlist
    set theSeconds to item 3 of HMSlist
    return round (theHours * (60 ^ 2) + theMinutes * 60 + theSeconds)
end getTimeConversion

-- progress_timer displays the elapsed time in a progress bar. For information on progress bars see: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html
on progress_timer(HMS_Time, timerLabel)
    set theTimeSec to getTimeConversion(HMS_Time) -- convert the HMS format to seconds
    set progress total steps to theTimeSec
    set progress completed steps to 0
    
    
    set startTime to (current date)
    repeat with i from 0 to theTimeSec -- begin at i = 0 to start the timer at 00:00:00
        set HMS_SoFar to TimetoText(i) -- convert the seconds so far to HMS format for display
        set HMS_ToGo to TimetoText(theTimeSec - i) -- convert the seconds to go to HMS format for display
        set progress completed steps to 0
        set progress description to "
Your IT Department needs to make changes to your Mac.  
  
Your workstation must be rebooted in order for these changes to take effect.
  
Your workstation will reboot in " & HMS_ToGo
        
        set progress additional description to ¬
            ""
        --"Time Elapsed:        " & HMS_SoFar & return & ¬
        --"Counting Down:        " & HMS_ToGo
        set progress completed steps to i
        set elapsedTime to (current date) - startTime -- get actual elapsed time for adjusting delay
        set lagAdjust to elapsedTime - i -- compute lag adjustment
        delay 1 - lagAdjust -- delay 1 second minus any cumulative lag that needs removing
    end repeat
    --set HMS_Elapsed to TimetoText(elapsedTime) -- convert elapsedTime back to HMS format for display
    set dialogText to null
    
    --set dialogText to "Elapsed Time: " & return & ¬
    --  "Nominal     = " & HMS_Time & return & ¬
    --  "Actual     = " & HMS_Elapsed
    tell me to activate
    
    --display dialog dialogText with title timerLabel & " Timer"
    return dialogText
end progress_timer

-- TimetoText converts a time in seconds to a time in HMS format (hh:mm:ss)
on TimetoText(theTime)
    -- parameters - TheTime [integer]: the time in seconds
    -- returns [text]: the time in the format hh:mm:ss
    -- Nigel Garvey points out this script is only valid for parameter values up to 86399 seconds (23:59:59) and offers a solution for longer times here: https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=134656#p134656
    
    if (class of theTime) as text is "integer" then
        set TimeString to 1000000 + 10000 * (theTime mod days div hours) -- hours
        set TimeString to TimeString + 100 * (theTime mod hours div minutes) -- minutes
        set TimeString to (TimeString + (theTime mod minutes)) as text -- seconds
        tell TimeString to set theTime to (text -6 thru -5) & ":" & (text -4 thru -3) & ":" & (text -2 thru -1)
    end if
    return theTime
end TimetoText
```

Here's a screenshot of the resulting output.

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any mechanism to change the button. However, clicking 'stop' should generate a result (e.g. error "User canceled." number -128.) that could be used in a handler in which you could throw up a dialogue that has whatever buttons you want. Then you add some text to this progress indicator suggesting that the user can reboot now by clicking 'stop' and following instructions.

Comment: I have suppressed the pop up dialog afterwards. I'm wondering if I can use the cancel action to trigger the immediate reboot.  Will have to play around with it.  Not the most elegant solution, but even CocoaDialog doesn't have any real flexibility with buttons in countdown dialogs either.

Comment: If you put the whole section in a 'try' block, you can include an 'on error number -128' and in that section, display dialog with your 'reboot' button and then whatever code reboots.

Comment: Is there is a particular reason for using the built-in progress rather than just the countdown in a window/panel (which can float above other windows)?

Comment: Thank you, Mockman, will give it a try and repost here to help others.  

Red_menace wanted a simple one stop shop progress bar flow using native AppleScript similar to what our customers would see on Windows workstations from ConfigMgr.